# Cross compile c program to x86_64 linux on m1 mac

Tags: c, linux, clang, cross-compiling, apple-m1

I try to compile a C program for x86-64 linux on my m1 mac, and here is the command I use

```
clang --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu test.c
```

But I am getting an error `fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found`.

It seems to be that I miss some dylib file for x86-64 linux. Does anyone how to solve it?

Comment: You need some kind of SDK to build against. Where did you expect `stdio.h` for Linux to come from?

Comment: @Siguza It can be a dylib file that I can directly link with. You don't have to make me feel bad to let me know that.

Comment: Install your preferred Linux in a VM. Install GCC there to make sure `stdio.h` exists. Run `clang --version` to check what is the correct value of `--target`. Copy the contents of `/` to your Mac (not everything is needed, but it's easier to copy everything). Add `--sysroot=/my/path` to flags to point to that directory.

Answer (score 3):

Quick solution - install prebuild cross compiler binaries

```
brew tap SergioBenitez/osxct
brew install x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```